# How can I merge two input into one? (gear mechanism)

Tags: gears

How can I merge two input into one? (gear mechanism)
There are a tube, a shaft, and a gear.
The shaft is in the tube and both of them rotates in same direction.
And I have to deliver the power to the gear at the bottom.
How can I merge two input and deliver it to one gear without interrupting one's rotation?
There would be no reverse rotation of gear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do that (it might require significant rework) is with the use of a differential /planetary gear system.

The planetary gear arrangement with the sun-planets-ring might lend itself more to the endeavour

[image]

i.e. attach:

- the red shaft to the *sun*
- the outer (blue) tube to the **ring**
- the gear to the planet carrier.

---

There are a lot of asterisks, i.e. what is the rpm on the output compared to the rpm of the shaft and the ring, however, since you did any information I assumed that you wanted to transfer power/torque.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a mechanism like a car differential, connecting the tube and shaft to the sides but in a reverse sense. And the output is where it is in a car is the engine shaft.[image: diff]